# yii2 ckeditor widget without model

Tags: input, yii2, ckeditor

i'm using yii2 dosamigos ckeditor extension.

```
echo $form->field($modelPatientTest, 'template_data')->widget(\dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor::className(), [
            'options' => ['rows' => 3,'value' => $templateData],
            'preset' => 'full',
            'name' => 'modalckeditor',
            'clientOptions' => ['height' => 200,'width'=>750]
        ]);
```

I want to use it without model so that i can set up custom name. like following

```
   <?php echo Html::textInput("TestValue[{$test->test_group_id}][{$test->id}]", $test_value, ['class' => 'form-control inputvalue']); ?>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly.

This is the way to use it without model, according to [2amigos](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget)

```
 use dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditorInline;

<?php CKEditorInline::begin(['preset' => 'basic']);?>
    This text can be edited now :)
<?php CKEditorInline::end();?>
```

EDIT:

If you want to change the name/id, there are 2 answer in stack overflow that might help you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557746/is-it-possible-to-set-my-own-id-to-ckeditor) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544832/how-to-programmatically-determine-name-of-ckeditor-instance/2546043#2546043)

Comment: There is a difference between CKeditor and CKEditorInline... I was talking about just ckeditor not inline...However i solved myself by following code...

            echo CKEditor::widget([
                'name' => "TestValue[{$testGroup->id}]",
                'id' => 'patienttest-template_data',
                'preset' => 'full',
                'value' => $templateData,
                'clientOptions' => ['height' => 200, 'width' => 750],
            ]);